# How following matrices equation is solved?

Tags: matrices

Suppose matrix $\mathbf{P}=[\mathbf{I_r} \mathbf{M}]$
 and $\mathbf{Y}=\mathbf{G_t}\mathbf{P} =\mathbf{G_t}[\mathbf{I_r}\mathbf{M}]=[\mathbf{G_t}\mathbf{G_t}\mathbf{M}]$.

if $\mathbf{G_t}$ has left inverse then how $\mathbf{M}=\mathbf{G_t}^{-1}(\mathbf{G_tM})$?

Comment: What do the $[]$ mean?

Comment: The matrix product does not care about which order you take it in so $G_t^{-1}(G_t M) = (G_t^{-1}G_t)M = M$ using the definition of the left inverse $G_t^{-1}G_t = 1$.

Comment: I am asking how $\mathbf{M}$ becomes equal to $\mathbf{G_t}^{-1}(\mathbf{G_t}\mathbf{M})$ following above definitions of matrices. $\mathbf{Y}$ was equal to $\mathbf{G_t}\mathbf{G_t}\mathbf{M}.$

Comment: The point @Winther  was: It doesn't really matter what you know about $M$ or $G$:  $M=M$ always holds, so does $M=1 M$ so does $M=G^{-1} G M$ if $G^{-1}$ exists (assuming [] are negligble)